# Can I make SQL 2008 Management Studio validate code for SQL 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2008

We have a production database running on SQL 2005. We are using SQL 2008 Management Studio. The issue we are having is that some of the stored procedures/functions we write get code that is compatible with SQL 2008, but not with SQL 2005. The newer management studio doesn't flag this as an error, but when we try to deploy a version, we get a large amount of errors. Is there any way to get 2008 Management Studio to validate code for compatibility?
Thanks!

Comment: It's true that SQL Server 2008's SSMS does not highlight syntax errors when working with a SQL Server 2005 instance, but you should still be able to use the *Parse* command (`Ctrl+F5`) without any issues. (Although most often *Parse* doesn't let you see the errors caused by erroneous names.)

Answer (score 2):

Even if you are using Management Studio 2008, you dev database should match the prod one. It is an extremely poor idea to develop against a 2008 databse when your prod database is 2005. You can still hook to 2005 databases in management studio 2008. Then you will find out immediately that the code doesn't work. In fact if you are attached to a 2005 database, it will only let you use 2005 syntax.  We attached to 2000 database for a long time until we got all the servers upgraded and it wouldn't let us write 2008 specific code as long as the database we attached to was 2000.

If, for some reason (and I stringly recommend against it), you will continue to develop against a 2008 database, I also suggest you look in Book Online for the new features of 2008 and make sure all your devs know which features they should NEVER use. Make sure your code reviewers check code against the list.

Comment: I'm honestly not sure how to tell if a database is 2005 or 2008. I think our DB might have been updated to a 2008 though as we have had a few issues with trying to deploy 2008 features on a 2005 DB. In particular, we've had troubles with the Date data type and declaring and assigning a variable in one step (DECLARE @ID INT = 0).

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Compatibility Level to SQL Server 2005 (90) under the Options section of the database properties.

Right click the database, select Properties, and then select Options.

Comment: That won't help. That is to keep old code running that wouldn't run on 2008, it willnot prevent you from using new features.